# Manga where the hero's party defeated the demon king but the demon king cursed them

Tags: story-identification, manga

I'm trying to find a manga that I once read about. The hero's party, after defeating the demon king, got cursed: the hero turned gay, the monk turned young, one turned into a girl, and the princess turned evil. They are trying to find a way to get rid of the curse while also trying to find the princess that turned evil.

The manga was black and white and I'm pretty sure that they got help from a witch that cured one of them but there was a time limit I think. I think I read it in August or early on. I don't remember the name of any character but I think the hero's name was Arthur.

Comment: That's a good start, but I think you can remember some more details that may help others locate this manga. Was it in color, or in black and white? Can you estimate when it was published, or when you read it? Was it originally in Japanese or in English? Also, I'm not clear on what you are saying. Do you mean to say that the hero was turned gay as a curse, or did the whole party get cursed by being turned young, female, evil etc.? Do you remember the names of any of these characters, or any distinctive phrases or sentences that they said?

Comment: The hero party all got cursed however everyone got different curse so the hero turned gay because of the curse the monk turned young, the princess turned evil but was gone and someone else I can't remember well but he was royalty and he was turned into a girl and the manga was black and white and I'm pretty sure that they got help from a witch that cure one of them but there was a time limit I think. I think,I read it in August or early on I don't remember the name of any character but i think the hero name was Arthur

Comment: I remember this one also.They had only 1 year before the demon king revive. There are also a ninja brother. The princess turn into maou after found out hero turn gay and think he betray her at chap 8.

Comment: That's right but I don't remember the name of the manga

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the description it is [Oretachi no party wa machigatteiru](https://myanimelist.net/manga/102462/Oretachi_no_Party_wa_Machigatteiru) ("Our Party Is Wrong"):

> A party of four heroes defeat the Demon King, however with his last bit of power he separates and gives each of them an unusual curse to make them suffer for the rest of their lives.

[image]